# How to customize google ads

Tags: ads, adsense

I'm interested in learning how to customize Google ads.

I know about changing the color, font, width, and height.
There appear to be limited choices of fonts and I cannot make the text bold.

However, I have seen several sites that have more customization in their ads than this. I want to do the same in Blogger. Does anyone here know how?

Answer (score 2):

Only premium publishers who have special relationships with Google can change the look of AdSense ads beyond what is provided in the AdSense console. You are unfortunately limited to the same settings that the rest of us have.

Answer (score 1):

"Google has a premium Adsense service exclusively for websites who receive more than 5 million search queries, or 20 million content page views per month." (c)